# Splitting a String by two things?

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Chapter11_ProjectPinochle {
public static void main(String[]args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String a;
    System.out.println("Type in your pinochle deals: ");
    a=sc.nextLine();
    sc.close();
    String[] deals=a.split(""); 
}
}
```

I need to split the String  I named `"a"` into a 16 spaced array. But the problem with the splitting is that the input is something like this: `ATKQQJ,AKQQ,KQQJN,A`. I need to split this into 16 parts and save it to an array I named `"deals."` I've tried `String[] deals=a.split("" && ",");` but apparently that isn't valid. I've also tried to split String a into 2 separate arrays and then put them together, but I realized I didn't know how. I want the output to be `["A","T","K","Q","Q","J","A","K","Q","Q","K","Q","Q","J","N","A"]` when the input is: `ATKQQJ,AKQQ,KQQJN,A`. How should I accomplish this?

Comment: I'm assuming the comma delimites each players hand.  What you need to do is split first on the players to get 4 substrings, then process each player's hand.  Doing it all in a single array isn't the easiest way to do this either.  Considering creating classes to better organize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Chapter11_ProjectPinochle {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a,b="";
        System.out.println("Type in your pinochle deals: ");
        a = sc.nextLine();
        sc.close();
        String[] temp = a.split(",");
        for (int i=0; i<temp.length; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<temp[i].length(); j++){
                b+=temp[i].charAt(j);
            }
        }
        char[] deals=new char[b.length()];
        for (int i=0; i<b.length(); i++){
            deals[i]=b.charAt(i);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you help me understand what this code does sir?

Comment: Can you add in explanations of what some things do? It might help me to more easily counter future problems.

Comment: first I split the string by the "," and put it to the temp array. and for the number of elements in the temp array, I ran a for loop for the length of each string in that loop and from that loop, I got each of the characters in those strings and appended those characters to a new string object "b". Finally, since you need all the characters in an array I got each of the characters from that new string one by one and added them into a new character array

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @jayblanchard I'm sorry what do you mean? do I have to further clarify my explanation

Comment: Instead of clarifying in comments, add your clarification to the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Split it out into individual characters
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("ATKQQJ,AKQQ,KQQJN,A".replace(",", "").toCharArray()));
//Split it into strings of a single character
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("ATKQQJ,AKQQ,KQQJN,A".replace(",", "").split("")));
```

Comment: Sir, your response has "ATKQQJ,AKQQ,KQQJN,A", but the code I currently have is for user inputs. Can I get something that involves user inputs?

Comment: @boiyeet Just replace the string literal `"XYZsomething"` with `a`, or the variable you use to store your user input.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
    String a = "ATKQQJ,AKQQ,KQQJN,A";

    // Split the string into comma-separated parts
    String[] parts = a.split(",");

    //Join those parts into a single string
    String whole = String.join("",parts);

    //Finally, split it up into individual letters
    String[] letters = whole.split("");
```

Could have also generated `whole` by removing the commas from `a`.